# Cannot connect via ssh to server with global IP address

Tags: ssh, networking, dns, port-forwarding, router

I have the no-ip service running on my raspberry pi, it updates the DNS (no-ip) whenever there is a change to it's IP address. 
I have enabled port forwarding on my router (Asus rt-n66u) ports 22 & 80, pointing to the intranet IP of the pi.
I have not adjusted any firewall settings, everything about the router is 'out of the box' including firmware.

When I ping the domain name, I get 0 packet loss.

When I try to connect via ssh:

```
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.7
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to [DOMAIN_NAME] [MY_GlOBAL_IP] port 22.
debug1: connect to address [MY_GlOBAL_IP] port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host [DOMAIN_NAME] port 22: Operation timed out
```

Is there something that I need to check with my router configuration and network setup perhaps?

Also note, I am able to connect via the local IP address of the intranet, i.e. 192.168.1.231 ssh just fine.

Comment: Unless your pi is missing a default route or something like that, this sounds like a question about your router's NAT and firewall, not about the pi. On topic if that router/firewall is Unix-based (but then you need details on its configuration), off topic if not.

Comment: Where are you connecting *from*?  Is the Pi running any firewall (`iptables -L`?)  As well as enabling port forwarding on your router, have you change the router to allow incoming ssh traffic (it's usually a two step process).  You may be better served asking this over at SuperUser, but it does depend on where the problem lies.

Comment: I am connecting from my LAN the same one the Pi is on. I upgrades the firmware to Asuswrt-Merlin and enabled ssh on port 22 in the admin settings.

Comment: `arget     prot opt source               destination

fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ssh`

Comment: install `tcpdump` on pi and run this: `tcpdump -nni any tcp port 22` as root and try connecting. If there are no new lines showing attempts, then problem is in your router setup.

Comment: I think the issue is that the router is behind one of those Comcast modem/router hotspot devices. Do I need to enable bridge mode on that device? I believe this is the case considering that the WAN indicated by my router is 10.0.0.X. Does this sound correct? Please advise further.